# Connecting Evolution to MS Exchange via MAPI

Tags: email, exchange, evolution

I've been trying to get some information about the MAPI plugin for Evolution - but it all seems to in pieces everywhere, and also mostly a couple of years old.

Anyone had any experience with getting Evolution connecting to MS Exchange via MAPI? Unfortunately, any other connection method (IMAP or WebDAV) is not an option - either because of not being allowed or just unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS it appears that the MAPI plugin for Evolution has been updated and will now connect to the Exchange server and download emails correctly.